# Select calls seems to not time out

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading, tcp, winsock

HI Folks,

I have a threaded C++ program where up to three threads are calling select on a three separate socket descriptors waiting for data to become available.  Each thread handles one socket and adds it to the readfds with a timeout of 300 seconds.  After select returns if there is data available I'm calling recv to read it.

Is there anything that I need to be aware of with winsock and threads because for some reason after a number of hours the select calls all seem to be not timing out.   Can a multi threaded program select from a number of threads without issue?

I know that I should have one thread listening to all three sockets however that would be a large change for this app and I'm only looking to apply a bug fix.

cheers,

Martin.

Comment: @martsbradley, without some sample code showing the problem there's not a lot we can do for you that isn't guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Without some code, I can only make a guess.  The most common reason for `select` timeouts to *not work properly* is that the `struct timeval` argument is not reset in every iteration of the loop.  Some (all?) `select` implementations update the timeout parameter to reflect the amount of time spent blocking.  However, this usually results in `select` not blocking.

Are you sure that `select` is the problem and you do not have something else going on like stack corruption, a memory leak, etc.?

**Edit**: I have used select from multiple threads on different sockets before under Windows without problems.  I forgot to mention this in the initial post.

Comment: The timeout structure is updated by select on a Linux machine, I've seen that before so I'm sure that I'm not repeating this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that it is ok to use the select on differnet threads because the following link says it is grand.

http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#threadsafety

Comment: This should be an edit to your OP, not a response to yourself.